# I am not able to create a new partition in my MacBook

Tags: macos, partitioning, boot-camp, disk-utility, macos-mojave

I use a MacBook Pro 13 early 2015 model running macOS Mojave, I have 2 partitions right now,(Mac partition APFS and Boot Camp NTFS)
I need to create one more partition to extend my boot camp partition.

When I use Disk Utility to create new MS-DOS partition it is showing an error. What do I do now ?

This is the error I get

```
Checking the fsroot tree.    
Verifying allocated space.    
Performing deferred repairs.    
error: nchildren of inode object (id 524386) does not match expected value
Deferred repairs failed.    
The volume /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely.    
Storage system check exit code is 8.    
Storage system verify or repair failed.    
Operation failed…
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot extend the Boot Camp partition with Apple software [& whatever you do **never** attempt it from inside Windows], nor can you add an additional partition from Disk Utility - the maximum is 4, which you now have, including 2 hidden ones. 3rd party software or a long, dark drive down arcane Terminal commands would be your next steps, but check you didn't damage the existing structures first.

Comment: how do I make a new partition with terminal?@Tetsujin

Comment: When I said "a long dark drive" I really meant it - I would avoid it & research software that can do this from a GUI... see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176557/85275 for just one example.

Comment: Can you suggest any 3rd party GUI  program that can make it happen ??@Tetsujin

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here, however in this case there are only 2 companies that make anything at all that can do this - take your pick...Paragon,  [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) & [CampTune](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/) & TwoCanoes, [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/)

Comment: I installed the paragon HDD manager, it shows 4 partitions: 1.EFI ,  2.Mac OS APFS, 3.Unformatted 16 MB , 4.BootCamp NTFS ..... Shall I delete the unformatted 16 MB partition and try making a new one in disk utility ??? @Tetsujin

Comment: Read through the manual until you completely understand it, & don't do anything without a solid backup.

Comment: I messed up everything :( , now I need serious help...I formatted the mac partition and deleted it so that It became un allocated space..i have bootcamp and windows 10 in it, and 200mb EFI partition..so 3 partition in total..i downloaded osx sierra dmg to my windows and made a bootable usb with transmac software...but during startup I pressed option and saw nothing other than my bootcamp partition …. I need help @Tetsujin

Comment: I made a bootable Gparted usb with yumi multiboot...still while pressing option at startup its showing nothing..@Tetsujin

Comment: So you didn't read the manual & you didn't have a backup? Sounds like your next investment will be data recovery software. I don't know why you thought you had to delete anything. The whole idea of using HDM is it can move the partitions without breaking anything.

Comment: I created a bootable USB of OSX sierra in windows 10 but when I restart and press hold alt, it only shows windows partition.bootable USB is not showing up @Tetsujin

Comment: This has really turned into a whole new question now. Have a search on here & https://apple.stackexchange.com & if you still can't find a solution, ask a new question.