# Can’t create new partition on Macos Mojave

Tags: partitioning, macos-mojave

I’m currently having the same issue as the person who asked this question: ([I am not able to create a new partition in my MacBook](https://superuser.com/questions/1425261/i-am-not-able-to-create-a-new-partition-in-my-macbook?newreg=fc0e6b890e314af985caff2ffd00299c)).

However, there weren’t any answers as to how I could go about creating a partition, as this person was trying to expand an existing one.

If it helps, this error also came up when I tried making the partition earlier:

[image: Error]

> error: directory valence check: directory oid 0x80062): nchildren (2)
> does not match direc count (0)